# Strange windows behaviour with DNS

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, dns

I successfully installed and configured knot-resolver on my dedicated server connected through VPN but I can't get it to work on my workstations.

Actually `nslookup superuser.com b.b.b.1` on my Win10 workstation gives the correct answer and I can see my resolver is correctly used (not 1.1.1.1).

Now, if I set b.b.b.1 as static DNS server in windows network settings I've got no more name resolution:

- `ping b.b.b.1` is ok
- `nslookup superuser.com` is ok and uses b.b.b.1
- `ping superuser.com` does not find host
- any browser can't resolve names

Network is set this way:

```
LAN
    IP=a.a.a.2/24
    GW=a.a.a.1
    DNS=1.1.1.1 or b.b.b.1
    DHCP=none
VPN
    IP=b.b.b.2/30
    GW=none
    DNS=none
    DHCP=b.b.b.1
```

`kresd` listens on b.b.b.1:53 and forwards to my dedicated's WAN.
`Flushdns` has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by setting no DNS on LAN connexion and b.b.b.1 as DNS on VPN connexion.